# Content Stretch Deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MDSpreadViewCell.png"]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imageView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(2./imageView.frame.size.width, 2./imageView.frame.size.height, 1./imageView.frame.size.width, 1./imageView.frame.size.height);
```

What is the equivalent code for the contentStretch of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Use a resizable image (`resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`). In Xcode 5 you can use a sliced image (set up in the asset catalog) for even more power.

There is a layer equivalent of `contentStretch` (`contentsCenter`) but I don't think that's a good idea with an image view.